# Test if bloc/cubit emits state in addPostFrameCallback

Tags: flutter, testing, bloc

I'd like to test the the following constructor:

```
class ChatCubit extends Cubit<ChatState> {
  final ScrollController _scrollController;

  ChatCubit(this._scrollController) : super(ChatState(chatIsLoading: true)) {
    _jumpToBottomRecursively();
  }

  /// Jump to the bottom of the chat repeatedly till the list view reached its
  /// "final initial" max scroll extent.
  void _jumpToBottomRecursively({double previousExtent = 0.0}) {
    SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (_scrollController.hasClients) {
        final currentExtent = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
        _scrollController.jumpTo(currentExtent);
        if (currentExtent != previousExtent) {
          _jumpToBottomRecursively(previousExtent: currentExtent);
          return;
        }
      }
      emit(ChatState(chatIsLoading: false));
    });
  }
}
```

I would like to test, if the cubit emits the correct state in the callback. The only way I know to test what a bloc/cubit emits would be to use `blocTest()` of the `bloc_test` package.

```
blocTest(
  'contructor emits state after frame is build',
  build: () => ChatCubit(),
  expect: () => [ChatState(chatIsLoading: false)],
);
```

The problem with this would be, that there is a `addPostFrameCallback` inside the constructor body. The callback would not get executed inside `blocTest`. I know I could test it with the `testWidgets` function:

```
testWidgets(
  'contructor emits state after frame is build',
  (WidgetTester tester) async {
    final cubit = ChatCubit();

    // can't expect emitted states here
  });
);
```

...but in `testWidgets` I'm not able to test if correct states are emitted by the bloc/cubit.

This is my dilemma. I need the behavior of both specific test functions (`blocTest`+`testWidgets`) in the same test.

Is there any way how I can test this? Maybe it's somehow possible to combine both test methods?

Edit: @Amir_P I edited the code snippets to make clear, why I want to emit in a post frame callback. In summary I want to make sure that the list view has scrolled down to its bottom before I emit that the chat is loaded, which will make the chat visible.

Comment: What is the reason behind emitting state in `addPostFrameCallback`?

Comment: @Amir_P I've edited my question to make clear why I emit state in a post frame callback.